# How to make Ethereum tx using web3.py?

Tags: python, web3.py, django

I am new to Ethereum. Using [pywallet](https://github.com/ranaroussi/pywallet), In my project, I had make ethereum wallet in local.
Infura API is used as a provider for me.

```
https://mainnet.infura.io/MYTOKEN
```

So I get balance of address generated by my wallet using web3.py.
And I want to send ether to some recipient(address).
But I can't make transaction and can't find docs about that.
Help me.

**EDITED ADD QUESTIONS**
What is the default gasprice? How to determine gasprice and gas amount?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is described in [web3py Documentation](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.sendRawTransaction)

Once you have your provider set and web3 instantiates you can do:

```
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(dict(
    nonce=w3.eth.getTransactionCount('yourAddress'),
    gasPrice = w3.eth.gasPrice, 
    gas = 100000,
    to='recipientAddress',
    value=web3.toWei(12345,'ether')
  ),
  'yourprivatekey')

w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

It will give the hash of the transaction. If you have your keyfile but you do not know your privatekey you can get it using [this tool included in web3py](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#extract-private-key-from-geth-keyfile)

```
with open('path to your keyfile') as keyfile:
    encrypted_key = keyfile.read()
    private_key = w3.eth.account.decrypt(encrypted_key, 'thepasswordforyour_keyfile')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! where do we get the txid?

Comment: the transactionhash is returned when you do `w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)`, so you can do this: `txid = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)`

Comment: Thanks again, but I am getting error message (on rinkeby):
`ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'}` the account has 18.75 ETH, private key is 32 digits hex from Metamask... is it ok?

Comment: I got it working, 12345 is too large,,, I thought it is a wei. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this solved your question, please accept the answer clicking on the check mark

Comment: I'll click on the check mark. But I have a question. The wallet is created using pywallet by me. What I say is whether above function: `w3.eth.account.signTransaction` is proper to my case. :) thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with pywallet but whatever wallet you choose you will have a private and public key in a keyfile, to use signTransaction the only thing you need is the private key, which you can import to python using the method described above.

Comment: thanks. I understand. I analyze my project and created wallet. That wallet was HDWallet. So sub-wallet(child wallet) has no private key. :)

Comment: In this case, how can I send transaction?